# Stretched texture after baking normal maps of cube

Tags: texturing, baking

I am a Blender/3D noob, I am trying to bake the normal maps of a high poly cube. My goal is to take the normal maps of the high poly cube, and apply them to a low poly version. I've watched a few tutorials, but always end up with the same artifacts.

Low poly mesh with high poly normal map:

[image: Low poly mesh with high poly normal map]

Low poly mesh UV:

[image: UV]

High poly mesh:

[image: High poly mesh]

Comment: Yes your map looks weird. I dont have that result with default cube, beveled, baked to another one. Weird are not only the corners but also missing beveled edges ... try to check your topology or position of your objects.

Comment: Change the baking settings. This is most likely related to the projection when baking, change the value (higher/lower) and then find the one that works. Of course, make sure that your objects are also overlapping perfectly.